# Jar file for com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory

Tags: websphere

I'm trying to connect to Websphere 8.0 (WAS)

I get exception

```
Exception occurred: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate      
class:com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
```

when running my program.

my jndi.properties is

```
java.naming.factory.initial=com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.ibm.ws.naming
java.naming.provider.url=iiop://<myip>:2810
```

May I know which jar should we use so that can connect successfully?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You certainly need the WAS_ROOT/runtimes/**com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.0.0.jar** in your classpath, where WAS_ROOT is the installation home of your WAS.

Comment: I don't have WAS and i need this Jar for this class to access mq using streamsets..please help.